# Path to read file from inside www folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a binary reader to read a file

```
BinaryWriter bw2 = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(@"c:\test\test6.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
```

the path i have set to is c:\test\test.xml 
However it needs to read the file from www folder hosted site
so www\test\test.xml
should it be ~\test\test.xml?
Not sure. 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need this function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Check out Server.MapPath() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=VS.90).aspx

So in your case, you're after this:

```
using (BinaryWriter bw2 = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(Server.MapPath(@"~\test\test6.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
{
    ...
}
```

Notice I added the using() which is a best-practice for working with expensive resources like files.

Of course, you really should seperate out file opening from object creation so you can have better diagnostics in your code.